# Can't we use SAML for securing microservices?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on, microservices, saml-2.0

Currently, Oauth2 is becoming the *de facto* for the security module for the microservices ecosystem.

Why can't we replace *Oauth* with *SAML* (or any other SSOs for that matter) and *JWT* with *SAML Assertions* (or equivalent data of the SSOs)?

Is it the simplicity of Oauth2 that makes us chose it or is there any other reasons not to use SSOs in place of Oauth for microservice authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is that SAML and WS-Fed typically rely on browser redirects to function.

OAuth is simple REST.

That said, if the IDP allows it, you could authenticate with SAML, get a SAML token, ask for the equivalent JWT token and then use that for the API.

Comment: SAML also supports ECP right? Instead of browser, we can use ECP.

Comment: Yes - but the only IDP I know off that supports it is Shibboleth.